# pandoc citations inside table

Tags: tables, citing, pandoc

How can I force pandoc to process the citations that are used inside a table/tabular environment?
A minimal example is:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline  [@referencekey] & Description \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I compile this using the following pandoc command

```
PANDOC_FLAGS=-s -N --template=template.tex -f markdown+yaml_metadata_block+tex_math_dollars -t latex
BIBLIO_FLAGS=--bibliography=mybib.bib --csl=acm.csl
YAML_METADATA=config.yaml
pandoc $(PANDOC_FLAGS) $(BIBLIO_FLAGS) $(YAML_METADATA) paper.mdtt
```

Comment: I doubt that this is going to work. You have a markdown document with inline LaTex code (the table), that you want to convert to LaTex?!
What would work is (although still cumbersome) a markdown document with a e.g. pipe-table with references in it, that is converted to LaTex.
If you need to go through LaTex, then maybe you should rethink your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue after a few hours of thinking. The key idea is to somehow get the numbers that pandoc could have used if it could convert the citations and replace them in .tex after pandoc processing!

The steps will be

1. find all usage of citations in the paper
2. Put a mapping of citation key --> [@citation key] at the end of markdown
3. Run pandoc to convert all citations including our mapping
4. Read each not converted [@citation key] inside the paper and replace it based on the mapping we have at the end of .tex
5. remove the mapping (optionally, you can put the mapping in \iffalse \fi to avoid this step)

OK, now this is my code:

```
PANDOC_FLAGS=-s -N --template=template.tex -f markdown+yaml_metadata_block+tex_math_dollars -t latex
BIBLIO_FLAGS=--bibliography=mybib.bib --csl=acm.csl
YAML_METADATA=config.yaml
NAME=paper

echo '\\iffalse' >> ${NAME}.mdtt
# find [@...] markdowns. Note that there can be multiple @... inside a bracket. We don't care, just replace the whole if they are not converted. 1) use sed to put each citation markdown in one line 2) find those lines using grep 3) remove the text after the citation markdowns 3) make the mapping. keys are put inside a table to not be converted using pandoc, values are just ordinary citation markdowns. I use 1::-- and 0::-- to recognize the map later in the .tex
sed ${NAME}.mdtt  -e 's/\(\[@\)/\n\1/g' |grep '\[[@a-zA-Z0-9_,\:\-\ ;]*\]'|  sed -e 's/.*\(\[[@a-zA-Z0-9_,\:\-\ ;]*\]\).*/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\\begin\{table\}1::-- \1\\end\{table\} 0::-- \[\1\]\n/g' >> ${NAME}.mdtt
echo '\\fi' >> ${NAME}.mdtt

pandoc $(PANDOC_FLAGS) $(BIBLIO_FLAGS) $(YAML_METADATA) $(NAME).mdtt footer.md > $(NAME).tex2

#bring them back. It needs another .sh file if you use it in a MakeFile because it seems that sed labeling doesn't work in MakeFiles
#put the mapping in a temp file, find the mapping using grep.  Sed expressions are to remove table environment, remove mapping arrow, concat lines (pandoc breaks lines after tables)!
grep '::--' ${NAME}.tex2 | sed -e 's/\\begin{table}1::-- \([@a-zA-Z0-9_,\:\-\ ;]*\)\\end{table}.*/\1/g' -e 's/0::-- //g' | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\(.\)\n\({\)/\1 \2/g' > temp.txt

cp ${NAME}.tex2 ${NAME}.tex;

#for each unresolved citation. Use grep to find lines with [@....], remove texts before and after it. remove [], 
for l in `sed ${NAME}.tex2  -e 's/\(\[@\)/\n\1/g' | grep '\[[@a-zA-Z0-9_,\:\-\ ;]*\]'|  sed -e 's/.*\(\[[@a-zA-Z0-9_,\:\-\ ;]*\]\).*/\1/g' | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' | grep '@'`;
do
       #find in the mapping and replace it
        v=`grep $l temp.txt | head -n 1 | cut -f 2- -d{`;
        sed -i  ${NAME}.tex -e "s/\[$l\]/{$v/g";
done
rm temp.txt

#run pdflatex here
```